# Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree. In Matlab

Tags: matlab

Here's what I entered:

```
h=abs((j*w*R*c)./((j*w*R*c)-(w*w*L*c)+1));
```

But I got this error:

> Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Can I have help understanding why?

Comment: What are matrices dimensions?

Comment: Have you tried to make a google search of this error? I did and get page after page of answers. So try to do it the right way, 1) open your favorite browser 2) enter the url of your favorite search engine 3) type the error and see if any of the hits gives you the answer you are looking for. In case they does not it is likely that your problem is more complicated. In that case 4) Ask a question here and make sure that the question explains the specific parts you need to know. Otherwise the question might get closed as a dupe, or you will get the same irrelevant answers as on other pages.